# What is the SQL Server "datepart", syntactically?

Tags: sql-server, syntax

There's something about the SQL Server time functions that I haven't noticed anywhere else in the language.

For example, let's look at the function `DATEADD()`:

```sql
DECLARE a_date datetime = '2006-08-31';
DATEADD(month, 1, a_date);
```

The 2nd and 3rd arguments are both expressions which evaluate to a value whose type I understand (`int` and `datetime`, in this case). But what exactly is the first argument? Is `month` a pre-defined global variable of some type? Is it a literal? Or a keyword? But it doesn't seem that [every valid `datepart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments) is in the list of [reserved words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Or is it some special syntactical category? If so, are there other examples of that category in the language? It doesn't seem I can treat it the same way as another variable or literal (`SELECT month` gives an error, for example).

Sorry if this is off topic for this site, but I wasn't sure which one it fit best under.

Comment: I'd say either keyword or enum

Comment: It's a literal, with the valid values (and abbreviations) defined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments). Unlike the other 2 arguments it can't be an expression, as using a variable in place of the literal won't work.

Comment: @IłyaBursov Good point about it being a keyword. I forgot to mention that possibility. I've added the idea to the question (as well as the issue that not all dateparts are reserved words).

Comment: "key word" and "reserved keyword" aren't synonymous. Most new key words added to the language have been context specific and not reserved. SSMS highlights them blue [as keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/color-coding-in-query-editors?view=sql-server-ver16#default-code-colors)

Comment: Or it highlights things like `nanosecond` blue. Month is also the name of a [system function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) so gets that highlighting instead.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, these are interesting distinctions. I notice that things that aren't a reserved word or system function (like `yyyy`) don't get any highlighting. I'd still like to know whether there's a specific term for this syntax or at least what the rules around it are.

Comment: It's a keyword but not reserved keyword. Such keywords can be used as regular identifiers. For example: select 1 as month. Other examples are: AT, DAY,APPLY
There are words which cannot be used as id, for example: DATABASE, KEY and others. They must be quoted, ie. [key]. The distinction is probably due to flights of fancy of the parser writer / keyword creator, or how often it already occurs in legacy code. Using reserved keywords is simpler for parser, because the word cannot naturally occurs. Downside is that such words cannot be used in normal code, which creates compatibility issues.